# preg_match meta name OR property

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How to impliment an OR here to match `meta` with both `name` and `property`

```
$html = '<meta name="title" content="title here..">
         <meta name="keywords" content="keywords here..">
         <meta property="og:title" content="og title here..">'

preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $html, $match);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <meta name="title" content="title here..">
            [1] => <meta name="keywords" content="keywords here..">
         // [2] <meta property="og:title" content="og title here..">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
            [1] => keywords
         // [2] => og:title
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title here..
            [1] => keywords here..
         // [2] => og title here..
        )

)
```

Comment: You should use a parser but there is an `or` in regex. Have you looked at any docs? http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: @chris85 prefer parser than regex ?

Comment: Yes, with a parser you don't need to worry about whitespace, order of attributes, encapsulation type of attribute values, etc. If this is just a regex question I think my previous link should answer that. HTML/XML aren't meant to be processed with regexs though.

Comment: Then I should try some thing like simple_html_doom_parser?

Comment: You should use jQuery. It's really great and does all things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As learned from the suggested link by @chris85, `(name|property)` will do this. My bad!

```
preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*(name|property)="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $html, $match);
```

Comment: If you dont need the `name`/`property` captured you can make it a non capturing group with `?:`. e.g. `(?:name|property)`